# SSIS - csv import

Tags: ssis, import-from-csv

I have a file of 700 000 rows and 90 columns and I had converted it to csv to upload it (using qualifier: "). The import worked but when I look at the table in SQL I see few text has moved to the next column.

In the actual file there is column called Comments and it has all type of characters(like *,|,| etc). Can this be the reason?

I tried doing the same import from .xlsb but it throws an error:

> Failed to start
>   project(Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.VsIntegration)

Answer (score 0):

If your fields have the same characters s the separator then of course the whole thing will break.

If you create the CSV with `,` as the separator and quotes (`"`) around the fields, you should be able to handle it in SSIS using these [instructions](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1316/strip-double-quotes-from-an-import-file-in-integration-services-ssis/) by adding `"` as the text qualifier.

I haven't tested this myself, but I would assume it works just fine.